# How do I export music visualizer animations?

Tags: animation, export

I was following a tutorial on how to make a music visualizer but no videos that I have found had no explanation on how to export it. I used a displacement modifier to animate the sound but when I export it with both FBX and glTF, its just a normal plane with no animation. Is there a setting on the export im missing?

Comment: It's not possible to export Blender's modifiers. They have to be applied before export which of course won't work if their effect is used for animation. Investigate baking your animation first and then exporting to GLTF.

Comment: You can export the animation to obj which makes all frames a different object, or you can use abc format, that developed for these kind of stuff.